# How do I load saved games from another hard drive in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

My `C:` drive is getting full and one of the big issues is all of my *Skyrim* saved games.  I've installed an internal SSD (`A:`) strictly for Steam games and have transferred Steam to that drive.  However, Steam/*Skyrim* still saves my games under `/Documents/My Games/Skyrim Special Edition/Saves` on my `C:` drive.  If I can move and run Steam from my `A:` drive, is there a way to save and use my saved games on my `A:` drive, as well?

Comment: *all of my Skyrim saved games* that I can't seem to throw away but I'll never use again... *those* go on the A drive. Also, if your C drive is a chip, that's where Skyrim should be (and its *current* save files). What you're asking for is uh... symbolic link? but that's a Windows question... and just a headache when HDDs are thousands of megs these days.

Comment: For each character, keep the first ten, the last ten, the auto saves and the quick save, and then delete the thousand in the middle. That'll take it from 200 gigs to less than 20.